# Relative path of the image in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a file structure like this:

[image]

I have all my constants located in `ConstantFiles/GlobalSiteConstants.js`.

The file looks like the following:

```
const GlobalSiteConstants = {
    HeaderNames: [
        "Home",
        "Login",
        "Contribute",
        "Feedback"
    ],

    Q1: {
        marginTop: "3rem",
        fontSize: "3rem",
        fontStyle: "auto",
        fontWeight: "700",
        OverallHeight: "40%",
        DisplayMessage:"Welcome to WebJsonify",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontColor: "#1d2d50"
    },

    Q2: {
        marginTop: "3rem",
        fontSize: "1.5rem",
        fontStyle: "italic",
        fontWeight: "300",
        OverallHeight: "20%",
        DisplayMessage:"Paper",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontColor: "#8d93ab"
    },

    Q3: {
        marginTop: "0",
        marginRight: "1rem",
        fontSize: "2.5rem",
        fontStyle: "oblique",
        fontWeight: "500",
        OverallHeight: "40%",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontColor: "#1d2d50",
        TextsToAnimate: ["View","Design","Customize","Create","Share"]

    },

    FrontPageImageDetails: {
        FrontPageImageLocation: "./assets/images/welcomepage.png",
        FrontPageImageAlt: "Front Page Image: Not Able to Load"
    }


};
```

Now Ihis is my `app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import GlobalSiteConstants from './components/ConstantFiles/GlobalSiteConstants';
import {Descriptor,HeadersVu} from './components/Decorative_Components/DecorationComps';

function App() {
  console.log(GlobalSiteConstants.FrontPageImageDetails.FrontPageImageLocation);
  return (
    <div>
    <Header HeaderNames = {GlobalSiteConstants.HeaderNames}/>
    <div>

    <Descriptor Q1 = {GlobalSiteConstants.Q1} />
    <Descriptor Q1 = {GlobalSiteConstants.Q2} />
    <HeadersVu Q1 = {GlobalSiteConstants.Q3} texts = {GlobalSiteConstants.Q3.TextsToAnimate}/>
    <img src = {GlobalSiteConstants.FrontPageImageDetails.FrontPageImageLocation} 
    alt = {GlobalSiteConstants.FrontPageImageDetails.FrontPageImageAlt}
    className = "ImageAnimationEffect"
    />

    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to import the image, but it shows issues with relative path. Does anyone know how to deal with this? Do I make any changes in my relative path?

On console logging the path, here's what it logs:
`./assets/images/welcomepage.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your react app with `create-react-app` or you are using `webpack` (or any other bundler, really) you can modify your constant file to have the image property like so:

```
FrontPageImageDetails: {
  FrontPageImageLocation: require("./assets/images/welcomepage.png"),
  FrontPageImageAlt: "Front Page Image: Not Able to Load"
}
```

Then in your component, `webpack` will take care of the relative path for you

Comment: Pleasure :) If this solved your Issue could you mark it as correct? It will help others looking for solutions to the same problem

Comment: Yes yes waiting for 3 more minutes before it allows me to mark it. :-)